# Ambiguous Prometheus metric value

Tags: prometheus

Hi guys I am collecting and trying to understand Prometheus metrics. There is some ambiguous value that I do not understand what it means.

```
{
            "metric":{
               "__name__":"xxx",
               "instance":"xxx",
               "job":"xxx"
            },
            "values":[
               [
                  1571837545.591,
                  "0"
               ],
               [
                  1571837605.591,
                  "0"
               ],
               [
                  1571837665.591,
                  "0"
               ],
               [
                  1571837725.589,
                  "0"
               ],
               [
                  1571837785.590,
                  "0"
               ]
            ]
         }
```

Inside the values collection I do not know what is the meaning of the random number such as 1571837545.591. Could you please help me to explain what it means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are timestamps: `1571837545.591` stands for `2019-10-23T13:32:25.591Z` (i.e. UTC).

So what you're looking at is a timeseries: the value was `0` at `2019-10-23T13:32:25.591Z`, `0` again at `2019-10-23T13:33:25.591Z, and so on over a time range of 5 minutes (5 samples, each 1 minute apart).

Comment: sounds great! but how can I format the value of the timestamps from `1571837545.591` to a common time format? and why does it have to encrypted this way?

Comment: Nevermind. I read through UNIX timestamp and understand this kind of metric. thanks a lot for your hints